# Receiving an error running gparted in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mount, gparted

I'm having an issue mounting an internal 3 TB harddrive. I'm receiving the following errors:

```
Unable to Access Location: Can't mount file
No Object for D-Bus interface
```

I ran gparted, and I see for this hard drive the following warning message:

```
$MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
Failed to mount '/dev/sda1': Input/output error
NTFS is inconsistent. Run chkdsk /f on Windows then reboot it TWICE!
The usage of the /f parameter is very IMPORTANT! No modification was
made to NTFS by this software.

Unable to read the contents of this file system!
Because of this some operations may be unavailable.
The cause might be a missing software package.
The following list of software packages is required for ntfs file system support:  ntfs-3g / ntfsprogs.
```

I tried to run "New UUID" and also "Check" to no avail. I'm not sure how to rescue this harddrive. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you Nmath for the format corrections. I'll try to follow that format in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda1
```

This results in the following output:

```
Mounting volume... $MFTMirr does not match $MFT (record 0).
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... 
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... FAILED
Correcting differences in $MFTMirr record 0...OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
Checking the alternate boot sector... OK
NTFS volume version is 3.1.
NTFS partition /dev/sda1 was processed successfully.
```

---

This answer comes from this question on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440841/ntfs-mftmirr-does-not-match-mft).

Comment: You still need to correct it in Windows with Windows tools. If you aren't dual-booting then you shouldn't keep NTFS partitions around.